# How to detect whether I need to use UHD, HD or SD in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm making a platformer videogame in Cocos2d-x C++.

What I want to do is really easy but everything I have found on the internet either doesn't work or it's for another programming language like Objective-C.

I have 1 spritesheet with 3 versions: one is **UHD**, other is **HD** and the last one is **SD**.

I just need to know how to tell the program what resources it should use.

I've tried to use this:

```
Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
auto winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize(); //gets window size (pretty obvious, isn't it?)

if (&winSize == "2048x1536") { //The device uses UHD graphics
    FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("UHD");
} else if (&winSize == "1024x768") { //The device uses HD graphics
    FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("HD");
} else { //any other type of resolution -> asumes it is SD
    FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchResolutionsOrder("SD");
}
```

But it just returns the winSize object memory address so it is impossible to work with it. I just need to see what the screen resolution is and then set the type of graphics I need.

Sorry if this is a really stupid question, I'm new to C++ and I haven't found anything on this.

Thank you

Comment: I could swear I've seen this title yesterday

Comment: "hdr" has nothing to do with resolution. hdr denotes a greater dynamic range of luminosity.

Comment: @bolov Yes, I was using the wrong term. With HDR I meant UHD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> const Size& getWinSize    (   )       const
>
> returns the size of the OpenGL view in points.

from https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d7/df3/classcocos2d_1_1_director.html#aa841a76e9016679ff92bc053e1a41718

with size : https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d0/d8c/classcocos2d_1_1_size.html

So I guess, something like this?

```
auto winSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize(); //gets window size (pretty obvious, isn't it?)

if (winSize.width == 2048 and winSize.height == 1536 ) { 
    //The device uses HDR graphics
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to this I can know what graphics does the game use, but it keeps giving me the following error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string`

Comment: Glad it helps, this error is probably not related with this question, try to make a minimal working example who reproduce this error and open an other question. I will be happy to help you again :)